# Adding specific weights to edges through dictionary

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have two dictionaries of nodes with edges like below:

```
all_nodes_edges = {20101: (20102, 20201), 20102: (20101, 20103), 20103: (20102, 20104)}
nodes_with_weights =  {20101: 20201, 20119: 20219, 20201: (20301, 20101)}
```

I've created the graph and default weights for all the edges in the graph with the below code:

```
g = nx.Graph(all_nodes_edges)
nx.set_edge_attributes(g, 1, 'weight')
```

I'm trying to use the nodes_with_weights dict to create weights of 2 on specific edges. How do I achieve this?. Do I have to loop through the dictionary or can I just use a specific nx function?

Sorry kinda new to graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!

```py
for u,v,a in g.edges(data=True):
    if u and v in nodes_with_weights:
        a = 2
```